# Algorithm for outer shapeof multiple 3d Shapes?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry

I'm looking for an Algorithm that returns the outer form of a collection of non touching 3d objects. Kind of what the Christos did in their art work: https://www.interviewmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/img-christo_133802515039-1000x752.jpg

Can anyone tell what that kind of algorithm is called or give some information where i could look?

Comment: I guess you mean the convex hull, but that image is not a good example

Comment: Have a look at Alpha Shapes and Concave Hull (not Convex).

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Alpha Shapes and Concave Hull whas what i was looking for!